# Can't assign cell value to double variable

Tags: vba, double

Good afternoon,

I have a sheet of data that has text and number values. I'm trying to assign the values to an array and check if it's within a certain range. Whenever I get a negative number I get a type mismatch error. I'm not sure how else to convert the data to a double data type. Here's a snippet of the code

```
Sub()
Dim amount1() as double
Dim h as integer 
Dim amtc as range, amtr as range


      ReDim amount1(AmtR.Cells.Count)
    For Each amtc In AmtR.Cells
            h = h + 1
            amount1(h) = amtc.Value
end sub
```

Any ideas to assist a brother?

Thanks

Comment: first check to see if it is a number `If isnumeric(amtc.Value) then` then use `cdbl(amtc.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

If `amtc.Value` contains an `Error` value, VBA cannot implicitly convert it to a `Double` (or any other type for that matter).

The value of a cell that contains a `#VALUE!` error will be seen by VBA as being of a special `Error` type. You can generate these error values yourself for testing, with the `CVErr` function:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(CVErr(xlErrValue))          ' prints "Error"
Debug.Print VarType(CVErr(xlErrValue)) = vbError ' prints "True"
```

You can use the `IsError` VBA function to determine if a `Variant` contains an `Error` value:

```
If Not IsError(amtc.Value) Then amount1(h) = amtc.Value
```

But that can still give you a *type mismatch* if the `Variant` contains a non-numeric `String`, so you can use the `IsNumeric` VBA function to ensure the type conversion will succeed:

```
If IsNumeric(amtc.Value) Then amount1(h) = amtc.Value
```

That's still an *implicit* type conversion though. You can use the `CDbl` VBA function to *explicitly* perform the type conversion:

```
If IsNumeric(amtc.Value) Then amount1(h) = CDbl(amtc.Value)
```

And now you have code that *does what it says*, and *says what it does*.

Comment: Thanks gents, I'll try out both options and see if something works.

Answer (score 0):

Good day Matt & Scott,

I've tried both solutions, one thing that's clear is that it's not Numeric. What is baffling me now is that it's only on negative numbers where I can't format the data type, but it's allowing me to convert the negative number to a string and I'm unable to convert the string to a double.

Hope you guys can shed some light...